# How to create a very dynamic LinqToEntity query?

Tags: linq-to-entities, dynamic-sql, dynamic-tables

I need to build a very dynamic Linq query over a varying number of tables.
For example, I have the related tables:
 
**Table_A**
 - ID
 - Name
 - Desc

**Table_B**
 - ID
 - Table_A_ID
 - Name
 - Desc

**Table_C**
 - ID
 - Table_B_ID
 - Name
 - Desc

I have a dictionary with information about the table dependencies containing:
  *tableName, parentTableName, foreignKey, parentPK*
Example:
 
  "Table_B", "Table_A", "Table_A_ID", "ID"
  "Table_C", "Table_B", "Table_B_ID", "ID"

-> tableInfo["Table_B"].ForeignKey will return "Table_A_ID" etc.

Now the user can select which columns he wants to see.
Examples:

**Table_B.Name, Table_C.Desc**
 or

**Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name**
 or

**Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name, Table_B.Desc, Table_C.Name**

This selection will is available in another list:
E.g for selection 3:
viewInfo["Table_A"] contains "Name"
viewInfo["Table_B"] contains "Name", "Desc"
viewInfo["Table_C"] contains "Name"

How do I dynamic create a query just using the needed tables and fields to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using the very interesting framework [NLinq](http://nlinq.codeplex.com/) found on Codeplex.
You just have to build a string containing your "normal" Linq query!

#### Citation from prject description:

NLinq is a framework focusing on reimplementing the Linq functionnalities in Visual Studio .Net 2003 and Visual Studio 2005 (C# & VB .Net) by providing a Linq grammar parser and a "Linq To Objects" execution environment. With NLinq you can take advantage of major C# 3.0 features right now, without requiring it.

#### Example:

```
Data sources used for the samples
        Person[] people = new Person[] { 
            new Person("Bill", 31), 
            new Person("John", 30), 
            new Person("Cindy", 25), 
            new Person("Sue", 29) 
        };

        // For testing physical links
        people[0].Friends.Add(people[0]);
        people[0].Friends.Add(people[1]);
        people[1].Friends.Add(people[2]);
        people[2].Friends.Add(people[3]);
        people[3].Friends.Add(people[0]);

        // For testing logical links
        Address[] addresses = new Address[] {
            new Address("Bill", "Redmon"),
            new Address("Bill", "Boston"),
            new Address("Cindy", "New York")
        };

Projections query = new NLinqQuery(
                @"  from c in people 
                    from d in people
                    where c.Age > d.Age
                    select new NLinq.Play.Person ( c.Firstname, d.Age )");

        linq = new LinqToMemory(query);
        linq.AddSource("people", people);


Result:
Sue (25)
John (25)
John (29)
Bill (30)
Bill (25)
Bill (29)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have done the same thing for a project I'm working on where the query is completely created at runtime based on selections made in the UI by a user.

I construct the LINQ queries using expression trees by using the classes in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace. It's very powerful but has a steep learning curve.

You can use [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/) to write queries and then dump the expressions to see what the tree looks like underneath so that you know how to construct the queries yourself.

For example, running the following code in LINQPad will generate a dump of the expression tree.

```
var query = from p in Puzzles
select p;

query.Expression.Dump(20);
```

[image: LINQPad Screenshot]

*So how does one actually write code that dynamically creates a simple LINQ query?*

Consider the following example which is simplest of queries:

```
var query = from person in data
   select person;
```

The following code will generate an equivalent query on the fly.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestLinqGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set up dummy data
            var data = new[]
                           {
                               new {Name = "Fred"},
                               new {Name = "Simon"}
                           }.AsQueryable();
            var dataType = data.ElementType;

            // IQueryable: data
            var source = Expression.Constant(data);

            // Parameter: person
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(dataType, "person");

            // person => person
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(parameter, parameter);

            // Expression: data.Select(person => person)
            var callSelect = Expression.Call(GetSelect().MakeGenericMethod(dataType, dataType), source, Expression.Quote(lambda));

            // IQueryable: data.Select(person => person)
            var query = data.Provider.CreateQuery(callSelect);

            // Execute query
            var results = query.Cast<object>().ToList();

        }

        private static MethodInfo GetSelect()
        {
            // Get MethodInfo of the following method from System.Linq.Queryable:
            // public static IQueryable<TSource> Select<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
            return typeof(System.Linq.Queryable).GetMethods().Where(
                method => method.Name == "Select" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
                          method.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == typeof(Func<,>).Name).Single();
        }

    }
}
```

You should be able to run this code by pasting it into a console application. Step through with the debugger to understand what each step does.

**Extra Info**

Looking at the implementation of `Queryable.Select` using Reflector can be helpful in understanding what needs to happen when writing a query dynamically. I've copied it below:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, int, TResult>> selector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (selector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
    }
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression.Call(null, ((MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult) }), new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) }));
}
```

Interestingly, the implementation of `Queryable.Select` simply creates a LINQ Expression representation of calling itself. The LINQ provider actually translates that expression into something else - TSQL. The `Select` method itself doesn't actually perform the select.

Your code should do the same thing - create LINQ expressions.

Once you are comfortable with how to do a simple select, you can look at adding `Queryable.Where` to the mix and other features of a LINQ query. I suggest leaving projections (`select new {x, y, z}` etc) to last because they are quite difficult. You will need to generate types at runtime in much the same way as the compiler generates anonymous types for you. `System.Reflection.Emit` is your tool for the job.

One of the nice things about this approach is that you can use it with any LINQ provider, such as LINQ to Entities, LINQ to SQL, Mindscape Lightspeed and the in-memory LINQ provider implementation provided by `AsQueryable`.

My code that generates LINQ expressions will accept an IQueryable and at runtime this is currently supplied with the Mindscape Lightspeed IQueryables, but could also be one of the others. Then in my unit tests I create test data using arrays of objects and then turn that into an `IQueryable` using `AsQueryable` which is passed into the LINQ expression generator. My unit tests can then generate all ranges of complex queries but can be easily tested without requiring a database. The sample above shows how this can be done.

Comment: Do you have an example for creating the query manually?
If I look at the generated lamda expression, it looks like that if I want to create that "by hand", I would have to handle strong typed stuff. Did you realize your solution like that?

Comment: I don't have any small snippets of code that I can share that will demonstrate the technique. The approach I'm using specifies queries in a higher level model and then translates the model into a LINQ expression tree that represent a LINQ query such as one you would write in C#. Then you can execute the query and get back the results.

You have the full power of LINQ using this technique but it is not trivial.

I will update my answer to include more info.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed informations!
But... the "quick run down" is to quick for me :-(
Could you please give me more information about how to code that?

Comment: I've written a small sample program for you and amended the answer.

Comment: How did you get LinqPad to evaluate `Puzzles`? How do you get it to work with Linq to Objects?

Comment: By dumping the `Expression` property of the `IQueryable<T>` interface. To get a LINQ provider for LINQ to Objects, you need to change your source collection (that implements `IEnumerable<T>`) into an `IQueryable<T>`. You can do that by using the `AsQueryable` extension method. i.e. `var q = from x in myCollection.AsQueryable() select x; q.Expression.Dump();`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) that can help you construct queries dynamically. I think you should take a look at this project.

Other than that, it is also possible to create queries in parts by querying a LINQ query. You can put conditional statements in your code and if some branch is followed then you can create a new query from an existing query by querying it again. The query is not executed until you request the results so performance-wise it doesn't matter much if you build up the query in small pieces or make one huge query from the beginning. Using this technique you can (based on the values of the inputs) build up structurally different queries that share some common parts whilst having the benefits of static typing and intellisense.

Comment: My problem is that i have a set of about 200 tables with some dependencies to other tables within that set. 
If I understood your idea with the re-queries, I think it's not possible to create a query with a non-fixed datasource ("query = ... in XXX), right?.
But XXX is not fix at designtime. 
All i have is the knowledge about the hierarchy of the user selected tables (and fields) to create the query at runtime.

Comment: @cew: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do from your question, but if your table is a variable and you have 200 tables you might want to consider if your database would benefit from a bit of normalization. For example if you have table_foo1, table_foo2, table_foo3 with identical columns then its better to just have a single table_foo with an extra column containing the type (1,2 or 3). But you will have to give more details if you want more specific ideas on how to normalize.

Comment: I have a lot of different, not normalizable tables with no hard coded relationship. The knowledge about the dependencies is retrieved from another data source. I have to join data from fields of different tables, the user has selected in UI.